# is this HTML valid? <ul> <li class="head">News roll </li> <li>News 1</li> <li>News 2</li> </ul>

Tags: html, html-lists

I am trying to have a header inside an UL
since you cant have H2 inside a UL
is it ok if use it the way i shown?

```
<ul>
   <li class="head">News roll </li>
   <li>News 1</li> 
   <li>News 2</li> 
</ul>
```

I was told by one of my friend, its not a proper way to do it and he apparently doesn't know the reason.

Comment: This is perfectly valid HTML ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is fine.

As for your structure, maybe you want to use the `h2` tag outside of the `ul`? (Assuming it's going to be a header for that list).

```
<h2>News Roll</h2>
<ul>
    <li>News 1</li>
    <li>News 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you @truth, that's what i usually do.. was curious to know if this was right :)

Answer (score 1):

Its a perfectly valid html. You can't put any tag inside a `<ul>` though, it has to be directly followed by an `<li>`. You can however, put any block level element inside the `<li>`. So you can have H2 inside li.

*As far as your friend is considered, he is wrong.*

Comment: According to HTML5 specs, the following is perfectly valid: `<a href="#"><div>Foo</div></a>`.

Comment: Further to what @Truth said, this is not an issue of block vs inline. This is an issue of `ul` vs `li` vs other elements.